# How do I convert my open-ssh public key to ssh2

Tags: azure, ssh-keys

While trying to create a Linux VM in Azure, I added my `ssh-ed25519` when suddenly:

> [Multiline SSH key must begin with '---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----' and  end with '--- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spxtk.png)

How do I covert my key into a compatible format?

**Edit:** It appears that the Azure portal doesn't recognize `ssh-ed25519` keys, I've contacted support. In the meantime, use a backup `ssh-rsa`, and you can plug it in without converting it into SSH2

Comment: Hey, were you able to connect with the converted key? I just ran into this problem, and... well, I have no such option as to use a backup.  I'm just left with a key that no longer works.

Comment: Hi @wvxvw, this is an old question so I don't clearly remember what happened. Did the solution below not work for you?

Comment: Nope. Azure still refuses to accept the key generated in this way. Also, Linux VMs no longer honor `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`... The only way to log into VMs is to set up password authentication. Azure tech support has troubles with English language, so he's still struggling to understand what the problem is, before we can even get to the technical details (the tech support doesn't seem to shine in that area either...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert an OpenSSH public key to SSH2 format using `ssh-keygen`, for example:

```
ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```